# Passing parameters to a Gearman worker

Tags: gearman

I've been looking into Gearman lately and I'm trying to figure out how I can pass a parameter to a Gearman worker that is started on the command line.

E.g. I can start a Gearman worker who's job it is to return the result of an `ls -lh`:

```
$ gearman -w -f list -- ls -lh
```

When the Gearman daemon has started it is now possible to call the `list` worker function like this:

```
$ gearman -f list < /dev/null
```

However, I'm trying to figure out how I can pass a parameter to the `list` function in the worker.

Answer (score 1):

http://stefaanlippens.net/gearman_setting_worker_process_arguments_through_xargs